# How to parse a Javascript regexp in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

First of all, I am not the one who is writing the regexps, so I can't just rewrite them. I am pulling in several Javascript regexps, and trying to parse them, but there seems to be some difference between them. Testing the example regexp on W3Schools, Javascript shows this:

```
var str="Visit W3Schools";
var patt1=/w3schools/i;
alert(str.match(patt1))
```

which alerts "W3Schools". However, in Python, I get:

```
import re
str="Visit W3Schools"
patt1=re.compile(r"/w3schools/i")
print patt1.match(str)
```

which prints `None`.
Is there some library I can use to convert the Javascript regexps to Python ones?

Comment: Look up `.match` vs. `.search`.

Comment: [Please be careful using w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python [`.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only matches *at the start of the string*.

What you want to use is instead is [`.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search).

Moreover, you do not need to include the '/' characters, and you need to use a separate argument to re.compile to make the search case insensitive:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "Visit W3Schools"
>>> patt1 = re.compile('w3schools', re.I)
>>> print patt1.search(str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10088e1d0>
```

In JavaScript, the slashes are the equivalent of calling `re.compile`.

I can recommend reading up on the [python regular expression module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), there is even an excellent [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 2):

Could write a small helper function so /ig could also work:

```
def js_to_py_re(rx):
    query, params = rx[1:].rsplit('/', 1)
    if 'g' in params:
        obj = re.findall
    else:
        obj = re.search

    # May need to make flags= smarter, but just an example...    
    return lambda L: obj(query, L, flags=re.I if 'i' in params else 0)

print js_to_py_re('/o/i')('school')
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2d8fe68>

print js_to_py_re('/O/ig')('school')
# ['o', 'o']

print js_to_py_re('/O/g')('school')
# []
```

Comment: This doesn't work for regexes with named groups. Unfortunately the JS style for named groups is different from that in Python.

Comment: @RJH not sure I'm following - could you provide an example of where it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to include the `/` characters and flags in the regexp, and you should use `.search` instead of `.match` for a substring match.

Try:

```
patt1 = re.compile(r"w3schools", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
srch = patt1.search(str)
print srch.group()
```